# How to work out if date is more than 2 years old using Twig in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, twig

I want to be able to display the text "OK" if a date is less than 2 years old, and if it's older than 2 years old I want to display "Over 2 years old". How can I do this using Twig?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this problem is explained on twig documentation about [date function](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/functions/date.html)

```
{% if date(mydate) > date('-2 years') %}
    OK
{% else %}
    Less than 2 years old
{% endif %}
```